# Add numbers using inner function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to create a function "sum" that adds multiple numbers using an inner function. e.g.
sum(1)(2) will print 3
sum(1)(2)(3) will print 6
sum(1)(2)(3)(4) will print 10 and so on

I wrote the following code which works for sum(1)(2).

```
function sum(num){
    function add (b){
        console.log(num+=b);
    }
    return add;
}
```

How can I extend this to work with multiple calls to inner function?

Comment: Currying and dynamic arity are not compatible.

Comment: There's some problems here. You need to pass b in somewhere.
Ideally this function will take 2 arguments, and add them together.

Comment: *sum* needs to return itself with the current value perhaps as a property or held in a closure. The trick will be clearing it the next time it's called.

Comment: Add `return add;` as the last line of the inner `add` function. I tried posting this as an answer but it was closed. Note that this *prints* the answer, but does not *return* it.

Comment: Thanks Bergi for pointing me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would handle it.
Just a single function that accepts 2 numbers. Adds those 2 numbers and returns the sum.

```
function sum(num1, num2){
    return num1+num2;
}

console.log(sum(11, 10));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PpsjJ/

Update: I think this is what you want. A function that accepts an array of numbers, and then adds them all together.

```
function sumAll(numbers){
    var result = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function(value, key){
        result += value;
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(sumAll([1,2,3]));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PpsjJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is summing variable number of arguments. What about this:

```
function sum() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    total += arguments[i];
  }

  alert(total);
}

sum(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Prints: 21

You can call `sum` with any number of arguments.

Comment: foo isn't being defined. You're also adding I. I has nothing to do with the numbers being passed in. If you change the numbers you'll end up with 15 still.

Comment: You want `total += arguments[i]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated it.